# Text Recognition in Sikuli-java-api (not sikuliX-api)

Tags: ocr, sikuli

SikuliX or Sikuli Script has Region.text() which returns the text value from the image on screen based on tesseract ocr.

Is there something similar in Sikuli-java-api??

I need to verify some text from screen and am trying to decide which of the two api should be used. Thanx for ur help in advance!

Comment: This is possible and I posted the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291954/changing-a-string-of-text-and-numbers-into-just-numbers

Answer (score 0):

No, only up on setting up the tesseract ocr, you would be able to read/validate text. if you are not able to download this OCR directly during installation try the offline version of this OCR and copy it to your local.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you wish to accomplish by recognizing "text", Sikuli can still recognize images of text. Text images are treated the same as any other images displayed. Sikuli on its own can't interpret the text in an image, however if you know what text you wish to see, and have an image of it for comparison, you can still validate whether or not it appears. Keep in mind that font and resolution changes will likely cause unreliable results.